# Can we change Log Shipping backup file naming convention

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, naming-convention

Seems the Log Shipping backup files naming convention (especially the date-time stamp in the name) is followed by UTC time, i believe that is default and standard.

I would like to clarify on following cases:

1. I'm wondering if there any possibility to change the naming convention to follow the date-time as per local time-zone from the server where the BACKUP performed.
2. Is the naming convention (UTC time stamp as suffix) really matter, since anyway the Log Shipping copy/restore job considers the LSN between each backup file to maintain valid log backup chain.

The aim is to avoid issues during compressing process that i'm following to maintain one zip file per day, and as per following screenshot it would combine additional files (20191015xxxxx) which are belongs different date (2019-10-16)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot automatically change the naming convention since it's controlled by sqllogship.exe (and if you manually change the file names I believe it will cause those files to be skipped.)
2. The naming convention apparently does matter regardless of the LSNs: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/log-shipping-skipping-files-with-different-naming-convention

I would personally just let them group based on their modified dates (since this is the true order they should be in) but if you want to compress them grouped by their name then you should control that with your compression tool / process, as opposed to the naming scheme SQL Server uses. (It would be simple enough to codify a small script to do this.)

Comment: Yes, we managed to do that for now with additional command lines (via SQL Job)

Comment: @Shekar Kola Ah gotcha, yup that's one way you can do it.