# SQL Log Shipping - What is the date time format used by transaction log file name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, log-shipping

Looking at my SQL log shipping file names (following is an example)

`Q:\Backups\LogShipping\MyAudit\MyAudit_20201027165400.trn`

What date time format is the transaction log expressed in (local military time, UTC time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What date time format is the transaction log expressed

Yes, it is **UTC** time with the format `dbname_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` (time is backup start time in 24 hours format). I think, following screenshot ([copied from..](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251221/can-we-change-log-shipping-backup-file-naming-convention)) can help for easy validation.

Left side: Highlighted is Log Shipping backup name with UTC datetime
Right side: **Date modified** column indicating the time in `+4 time-zone`

[image]

Comment: This is correct, UTC time. I also provided an answer to your linked question above, hopefully that's some help.